# Failed to deploy new revision in Azure Container App

Tags: azure, deployment, revision, azure-container-apps

Im using Azure Container App to deploy my application but i have gotten an issue with deploying new revision to deloy new change for my app since last Friday. Do anyone know how can i resolve it? This is the first time i faced this issue.

Thanksss

**Activity log:**
[image]

Comment: Are you dpeloying with bicep / az cli other ? Looks like you this property is not recognized `additionalPortMapping`.

Comment: `additionalPortMapping` is in preview so may you need to use a newer api version? Also could you add your infra as code.